# What is the format I should write the command to SSH into Linux VPS?

Tags: terminal, ssh, unix

I am trying to use SSH and log in from the terminal into a Linux VPS.

I have tried a few variations around the following:

```
ssh [user]@[hostname].[my.ip.address.xx]:22
```

and keep getting:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname [hostname].[ip address]:[port]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I have verified that my VPS works fine logging in from Windows with Putty, so I am sure I have something mixed up.

What is the format I should write this SSH command in?

Comment: Is the VPS hosted? Or do you run the VPS yourself?

Comment: hosted, but answer below worked. I was trying to append the port, hostname, and username (since the error message suggest I needed to), but ssh [my ip] worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a hostname, or IP address. Not both.

The hostname will only work if there is a resolvable DNS entry.
The IP address should always work as long as you use a publicly routed or otherwise reachable one.
You don't have to specify port 22, it is the assumed default when otherwise unspecified.

Comment: wow, do I feel like an idiot; aka thanks. (marking as answer in 8 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use both hostname and ip adress use `-W` argument to set the host (`ssh ip -W host:port`)